# In ReactJs change the color of a node element dynamically by looping through string

Tags: reactjs

trying to change string variable from `React.Children.map`, then `React.cloneElement` to change the color. I have a Title on my homepage. I want to update node color of each character within the title string. Trying to do it this way, but getting en error of :  `Cannot read property 'colorString' of undefined`

```
const LetterStyle = React.createClass({
  colorString: function(value){
    this.setState({color: "green"});
  },

  render: function(){
    const colorArray = []
    var childrentWithProps = React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, (child, i) => {
      for (var i=0; i<child.length; i++){
        return React.Children.map(child[i], function(content, i) {
          if(content !== " "){
            React.cloneElement(content, { colorString: this.colorString })
          }
        });
      }
    })

    return(
      <h1 className="lead" ref="lead">
        <span>{childrentWithProps}</span>
      </h1>
    );
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are losing the `this` reference by the time you get to the line                              `React.cloneElement(content, { colorString: this.colorString })`

Try to define `var that = this`; right after the `render function() {`
 like

```
  render: function()
    {
      var that = this;
      const colorArray = [] to preserve the properties of `this`.
```

and change the line to 
`React.cloneElement(content, { colorString: that.colorString })`

Also, I would suggest reading the differences between `let`, `var`, and `const`. In ES6 syntax, `var` is generally unnecessary, and mixing it with `const` and `let` can get confusing. Read more about the differences here:

[What's the difference between using "let" and "var" to declare a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable)

Answer (score 0):

This is the first time I've seen an implementation of .map and forEach from the  [**React Top-Level API**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html). They differ in their usage from their native JavaScript cousins.

There are a couple of problems with your code.

***1st Problem that causes your error:***

The docs for the latter state that `React.Children.map` and `React.Children.forEach` take two arguments, the first being a keyed fragment or array of children and the second being a callback whose only argument is the value that this will be set to within the [**`React.Children.forEach`**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.children.foreach) and [**`React.Children.map`**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.children.map) calls.  Their signatures are as follows:

```
React.Children.forEach(children, function[(thisArg)])

React.Children.map(children, function[(thisArg)])
```

The solution then is to not pass in to arguments but one into either call in order to remove your error.

*As an example*, your resulting `.map` call would look like this:

```
return React.Children.map(child[i], function(this){
  if (content !== " "){
    React.cloneElement(content, { colorString: this.colorString });
  }
});
```

---

***2nd problem worth mentioning:***

You have used forEach here which will effectively iterate over the `this.props.children` array.

Inside it you are referencing the current value being iterated over `child`and are running a for loop over that element to in turn get to your `.map` call.

This doesn't look correct for your application here as `child` most likely represents a single component or React element rather than an array to be looped over again.

Solution: use the for loop ***or*** the forEach here, but **not both**